# Express not serving static files on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

// Serving static files

app.use('/static',express.static('static'));
```

I am using the above code to serve static files but when i go on the server it shows:
It is showing ***"cannot get /static/index.js"***
index.js is the file I want to serve in my static folder

Comment: Can you show the project directory ?

Comment: Try this: app.use(express.static('static'));

Comment: @aastik-chaudhary Assuming your directory is `./static/index.js` and your url is `http://localhost/static/index.js`, your code is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the standard syntax.

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

Here "/static is the path prefix and public will the location from where the express will serve your files.
for example your files contains in public folder will be served using

```
http://localhost:port/static/index.html
```

You can also use

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

to server files like

```
http://localhost:port/index.html
```